# Antiparticles in Feynrules Lagrangian

Tags: packages, physics, feyncalc

I am trying to implement a simple extension of the SM to Feynrules, generating the Lagrangian in a Mathematica notebook file. I am wondering about the following:

1. Is there a way to explicitly use the antiparticle fields in the Lagrangian? Say, in the SM.fr file there is a W-boson defined in the following way:

   ```
   V[3] == {
   ClassName        -> W,
   SelfConjugate    -> False,
   Mass             -> {MW, Internal},
   Width            -> {WW, 2.085},
   ParticleName     -> "W+",
   AntiParticleName -> "W-",
   QuantumNumbers   -> {Q -> 1},
   PDG              -> 24, 
   PropagatorLabel  -> "W",
   PropagatorType   -> Sine,
   PropagatorArrow  -> Forward,
   FullName         -> "W"},
   ```

Now if I write down a term using W[mu], will it be W+ (positively charged one)? If yes, how can I call W- field?

2. Then if I want to add a new (Dirac) fermion to my theory, I initialize it as:

   ```
   F[102] == {
   ClassName   -> psi,
   SelfConjugate   -> False,
   Mass        -> {m,Internal},
   Width       -> {W,1},
   QuantumNumbers  -> {Q -> -1}, 
   PropagatorLabel -> "psiC",
   PropagatorType  -> Straight,
   PropagatorArrow -> True,
   ParticleName    -> "psimimus",
   AntiParticleName -> "psiplus",
   FullName        -> "psi"}
   ```

   If I then write down the kinetic term `LNEWkin := I/2 psilbar.Ga[v].del[psil, v]`, would it include in fact 2 termc for psiminus and psiplus?
3. Can I explicitly use psiminus (psimipusbar), psiplus (psiplusbar) in the Lagrangian?

I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: Are you talking about this?http://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/attachment/wiki/StandardModel/SM.fr

Comment: Yes, so this is the SM.fr file I meant. After initializing field and parameters in the file, I upload it to the Mathematica notebook and write the Lagrangian in the *.nb file directly.

Comment: This is the old code. It is necessary to rewrite it at least for 11.3. You can modify the code at your discretion. But you need to do an update.

Comment: So can I use the SM.fr file from the latest version of feynrules here https://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/? 

Ok, now I see that I can call Wbar, so it probably gives me W-. I suspect that, in the same way, calling psi gives psiminus and calling psibar gives psiplus but is there a way to check the quantum numbers of the specific particle in Mathematica? For example, something like Charge[psi]?

Comment: Everything is possible, but for this we need to test `FeynCalc` and `SM.fr`.